# Give delay in JavaScript after execution

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, timedelay

```
document.addEventListener("wheel",changeTopicBackground);

function changeTopicBackground(){
    if(document.getElementById("topicBackground").style.getPropertyValue("background-image")===`url("yy.jpg")`){
        document.getElementById("topicBackground").style.backgroundImage = "url('firstDevil.png')";
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("topicBackground").style.backgroundImage = "url('yy.jpg')";
    }
}
```

I've tried setTimeout() and setInterval() also, but if I use setTimeout inside the function then it'll execute the block inside the function after that time... and setInterval will repeat which is not desired.

Question is: ***How can I stop taking wheel event listener for 1sec after the code inside the function is executed?***

Comment: look up debouncing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the listener when the function fires and use `setTimeout` to restore it after one second:

```js
document.addEventListener("wheel", changeTopicBackground);

function changeTopicBackground() {
  console.log("wheeled!")
  document.removeEventListener("wheel", changeTopicBackground)
  setTimeout(() => document.addEventListener("wheel", changeTopicBackground), 1000)
}
```